# How to create thumbnail for video in some http path

Tags: android

I have some http path which contains video file.Now i have to upload this video file directly from

http path to FTP server.Its working fine.But is it possible to create thumbnail for that video

while uploading.If possible how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are coding for api level 8 and above, you could try [ThumbnailUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html)

Comment: only local path sdcard